# TestNG test cases are not compiling when i do project -> clean

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, testng

I am using Spring, TestNG, Eclipse, Maven, Mac OS

**Scenario is**

I am doing some changes in my test cases ( TestNG test cases ),

Then i do Project -> Clean in eclipse

Now i am running the test file, but the changes not updated.

I suspects that the test files are not compiled.

I can run the server and i can run my webservices

But if i run maven test ( mvn test ), the entire code is compiling including test cases.

So to run the test cases i am running mvn test command only.

Not able to run through eclipse.

**Eclipse config:**

Auto build on

In Java build path the test package is included

If you need any more info i'll provide.

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
    Cannot find class in classpath: com.***.***.model.***.case.CaseModelImplTest
        at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:76)
        at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:68)
        at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:54)
        at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:512)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:788)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198)
        at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
        at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
        at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:170)
        at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:304)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:86)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:199)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:170)
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue? What helped you?

Answer (score 4):

It seems , you are not included your Test case class into the build path. Right click on your Project folder, go to the project **properties->src**
include your Testcase src folder by checking it.
Now it should run.

Answer (score 4):

Open the Problems view. In Eclipse go to Window->Show View->Problems. It will list out all the failures while compiling the code.

Comment: Really helped solve my problem. my excel data sheet was open and build was not successful since file is open.

Answer (score 3):

Are the test cases being compiled, but to the wrong directory? They need to be compiled to test-classes not classes. In your build path, you need to set your Output folder to be

> PROJECT/target/test-classes

This is true for all test resources (including src/test/java & src/test/resources).

Edit your project properties in Eclipse, select `Java Build Path`, and then in the Source tab, you'll see all of your source directories. Each one has an output folder. This output folder needs to be as above.

Comment: I can find this ( PROJECT/target/test-classes ) directory, but inside there is no class files after the Project -> clean.
But other files are available in PROJECT/target/classes.
Do i miss any eclipse configuration?

Comment: I have another project in the same workspace. If i do maven clean and do Project -> clean, the test class files are generated in target -> test-classes folder. I think problem with that specific project config.

Comment: i am using aspectj, will it be a problem?

Comment: Thank you!  Ended hour of frustrating behavior.  I assumed m2e would set this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Project --> Clean`

That worked for me with similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your `testNG.xml` file for correct test because I got the same error and it was because the wrong test name was entered.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!This does not provide an GOOD answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. Please read the guidelines for good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 0):

is your test folder added as a source folder in Eclipse? If it isn't it won't be included in the build.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by:

1. Changing the build path / deleting some of the wrong ones
2. Cleaning the project

Answer (score 0):

I think some time we get this error if your test class is in default package and in Testng.xml, you specify as below -

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
</listeners>
<test name="Test">
    <classes>
        <class name=".Test1" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

Here in above, I moved my testclass from default package to some package and also updated testng.xml as below - and everything started working.

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
</listeners>
<test name="Test">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sigma.rest.api.Test1" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

I hope this helps you... if issue still exists, try above options.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project artifacts like excel, property files, xml files etc are open in text editors etc. ( if yes please close them and do rebuild )

When you clean and rebuild make sure all project dependent files are closed and you do build.