# what TestNG test is not latest I wrote

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, testng

I'm using Spring,Hibernate and Maven in my web project.
And I use TestNG to test our project.
There's a problem: When I want to test one test file, I right click in edit panel, and run as->testng test, then TestNG automaticlly run this test class in current edit panel. But I found that it was not the latest code I wrote.

How and Why?

Does someone else met this problem before?

Comment: Looks like an IDE problem.  You have not mentioned the IDE involved - Eclipse, maybe?  How about building again and trying?

Comment: Yes, I use the eclipse(indigo) version. I clean and rebuild the project but it not works.

Comment: Do you have "Build automatically" enabled?

Comment: Yes, I have. And after I ran maven test all the project(not a single test file), Then I ran testng test a single file, it is the latest code　again. But I think this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [TestNG test cases are not compiling when i do project -> clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399404/testng-test-cases-are-not-compiling-when-i-do-project-clean?rq=1)

Had the same problem and it was the output folder of the test classes. By default it's test-classes but I changed it to classes as Jetty seems to have a problem and excludes those at startup but I'm starting it to test the app.

Anyway, change it back to test-classes and run As works again, to work around the Jetty issue you have to uncheck the test classpaths, run jetty (which fails depending on your scenario), stop Jetty, check the test classpaths, now everything is supposed to work as expected.